# Can I create an iso using the Linux cmd from uup dump?

Tags: android

I'm looking to create an iso image but using my android is it possible to install Ubuntu through termux and run the uup dump cmd for Linu.sh fie

Comment: @karel if I understand this question correctly, it asks how to install Ubuntu on Android using Termux to run UUP dump, while the proposed duplicate is about installing Ubuntu (on a PC) from phone.